# How to use Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams in Bot Service with Dotnet Core 2.2

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'am currently implementing a teams bot which needs access to the conversation user list and their e-mail addresses.

I have tried many samples and also own implementations with the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams Package in the newest beta 4.0 version... but no way to find a solution... With the latest stable version 0.9.0 it's only possible to use it in dotnet v4.6.

Has someone an idea or can tell me how to get the teams channel and conversation context like on other channels?

BR

Added Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams in version 0.9.0 and beta 4.0. Tried to get the teams context and the members "AsTeamsMembers".

Using BotBuilder SDK v4.

Another Idead: Is there a way to get the channel and user ids with the bot without the SDK? The default conversation context is not working in Teams... If yes we can send the result to a Azure Function and access the graph api from there!

Comment: Are you using BotBuilder SDK v3 or v4?

Comment: I'am using BotBuilder sdk v4

Comment: Per the [readme](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/blob/master/README.md), it looks like it won't work currently with Bot Framework SDK v4.

`Note that the Bot Builder Extensions does NOT yet work with Bot Framework SDK 4.x. It currently only works with Bot Framework SDK 3.x.` I'll look for any possible alternatives.

Comment: In the beta 4.0 Version it looks like it works... but currently there is also no way with this version... It looks like Teams isn't on the same level as other channels...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution... it’s not easy currently because the documentation is not released for the teams bot api connector.

1. you need the following SDK‘s
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Teams

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams/4.0.0-beta1

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams/4.0.0-beta1

2. Add Teams context to your turn context by register the teams context middleware like in the following example

https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet/blob/1d557dbd9a3196a7eb668f8ebe8e2424f9a31964/CSharp/Samples/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.AuditBot/Startup.cs

3. Access the context like in the following example:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams-dotnet/blob/1d557dbd9a3196a7eb668f8ebe8e2424f9a31964/CSharp/Samples/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.AuditBot/MessageActivityHandler.cs

Have fun with teams and botframework v4.0